# error with MySQL SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I always get a syntax error on the following inner join:

```
SELECT 'myapp_instagram_shop'.id 
FROM 'myapp_instagram_shop'  
INNER JOIN  'myapp_instagram_shop_picture' 
    ON  'myapp_instagram_shop'.id =  'myapp_instagram_shop_picture'.shop_id;
```

Error is:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''myapp_instagram_shop'
INNER JOIN 'myapp_instagram_shop_picture' ON 'sh' at line 1
```

Comment: wrap table names in ` - not quotes - \`myapp_instagram_shop\` same goes for pseudonyms. \`myapp_instagram_shop\`.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT myapp_instagram_shop.id FROM myapp_instagram_shop  INNER JOIN  myapp_instagram_shop_picture ON  myapp_instagram_shop.id = myapp_instagram_shop_picture.shop_id;
```